# SQL query to find the top 3 in a category

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

Calling all sql enthusiasts!
Quick info: using PostgreSQL.

I have a query that return the maximum number of likes for a user per category. **What I want now, is to show the top 3 users with the most likes per category.**

A helpful [resource](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) was using this example to solve the problem:

```
select type, variety, price
from fruits
where (
   select count(*) from fruits as f
   where f.type = fruits.type and f.price <= fruits.price
) <= 2;
```

I understand this, but my query is using joins and I am also a beginner, so I was not able to use this information effectively.

Down to business, this is my query for returning the MAX likes for a user per category.

```
SELECT category, username, MAX(post_likes) FROM (
SELECT c.name category, u.username username, SUM(p.like_count) post_likes, COUNT(*) post_num
FROM categories c
JOIN topics t ON c.id = t.category_id
JOIN posts p ON t.id = p.topic_id
JOIN users u ON u.id = p.user_id
GROUP BY c.name, u.username) AS leaders
WHERE post_likes > 0
GROUP BY category, username
HAVING MAX(post_likes) >= (SELECT SUM(p.like_count) 
                          FROM categories c 
                          JOIN topics t ON c.id = t.category_id 
                          JOIN posts p ON t.id = p.topic_id 
                          JOIN users u ON u.id = p.user_id WHERE c.name = leaders.category
GROUP BY u.username order by sum desc limit 1)
ORDER BY MAX(post_likes) DESC;
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. I am having a difficult time wrapping my head around this problem. Thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the most likes per category, use window functions:

```
SELECT cu.*
FROM (SELECT c.name as category, u.username as username, 
             SUM(p.like_count) as post_likes, COUNT(*) as post_num,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.name ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM categories c JOIN
           topics t
           ON c.id = t.category_id JOIN
           posts p
           ON t.id = p.topic_id JOIN
           users u
           ON u.id = p.user_id
      GROUP BY c.name, u.username
     ) cu
WHERE seqnum <= 3;
```

This always returns three rows per category, even if there are ties.  If you want to do something else, then consider `DENSE_RANK()` or `RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Also, use `as` for column aliases in the `FROM` clause.  Although optional, one day you will leave out a comma and be grateful that you are in the habit of using `as`.